# SOQL query to extract only the most recent attachment IDs

Tags: soql

I’m trying to create a SOQL query that returns attachment IDs from a custom object (Invoice__c) related to Account.

The tricky part is to extract only the most recent attachment from each Invoice__c. Please note, an Account may have more than one invoice object, each with several attachments.

I was able to create the following query:

**Select Id FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId IN (SELECT Id from Invoice__c WHERE Account_ID__c = 'xxx')**

But the problem is I’m getting ALL attachments, whereas I need only the most recent Attachment from each invoice. The result should be multiple Id’s, but not all.

If I add **"ORDER BY Createddate LIMIT 1"**, then, as a result, I'm getting only 1 Id, which is not what's required.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a subquery for this:

```
select (select id from attachments order by createddate desc limit 1) from invoice__c
```

The result will be a list of Invoice__c records, with a child record for each attachment:

```
for(Invoice__c invoiceRecord: results) {
  for(Attachment attachmentRecord: invoiceRecord.Attachments) {
    // most recent attachment for that invoice here
  }
}
```

Comment: The nested statement does the trick! However, as an output, I get Id's with additional symbols: trueAttachment00PD00000xxxUo9MAE00PD00000xxxUo9MAE1,trueAttachment00PD00000yyy99KMAS00PD00000yyy99KMAS1. How do I get rid of excessive symbols? I only need the following Id's  00PD00000xxxUo9MAE and 00PD00000yyy99KMAS

Comment: @EdT. They shouldn't be there. I presume you're seeing this in a debug statement, so it's probably something you've included in the debug statement.

Comment: You're right, I'm using the query in Conga Mail Composer.